# Where can I find the syntax for macos spctl (gatekeeper) rules?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, certificate, code-signing, gatekeeper

I'm trying to code-sign an electron app for submission to the "Mac App Store". As expected, it has been a tremendous pain for 101 reasons.

However, I have now discovered a ray of light in that spctl has an undocumented --list option (well, it's not in --help or the man page):

```
spctl --list
```

which lists all of it's rules. Wow! maybe now you can find out the reason why, (e.g.):

```
spctl --assess -vvvv /Applications/XYZ-dev.app
```

Responds with:

```
/Applications/XYZ-dev.app/: rejected
origin=Mac Developer: XXXX YYYYY (ZZZZZZ)
```

With no further diagnostics being apparent.

The trouble is that the relevant rules output by sptl --list look like:

```
10[Mac App Store] P10 allow install
        anchor apple generic and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.10] exists
5[Mac App Store] P10 allow install
        anchor apple generic and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.10] exists
4[Mac App Store] P10 allow execute
        anchor apple generic and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9] exists
```

The first line is easy, but I can't find anywhere, the syntax for the second, e.g.

```
anchor apple generic and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9] exists
```

What kind of sorcery is this? If we could figure this out, we could understand why their gatekeeper is not working.

Also, notes for: XYZ-dev.app:

1. Hardened runtime is disabled but sandbox is on in the entitlements (Surpising, but it's not required for Mac App Store, right? (https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/hardened-runtime-sandboxing.html))
2. I copy to /Applications after signing (Otherwise you get XYZ Helper not found errors).
3. I don't think it's an entitlements problem as spctl rules don't seem to be looking at them. It's spctl that's failing.
4. I'm testing with a locally provisioned dev build using "Mac Developer" cert but will be using "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" for uploading to the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
anchor apple generic and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9] exists
```

[basically means](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/RequirementLang/RequirementLang.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH5-SW1) that the certificate should contain the field 1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9. That field is a custom extension to X.509 certificates that is for Mac App Store Application Software Signing.

Similarly 1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.10 is a custom extension to X.509 certificates for Mac Installer Package Submission Signing.

The first part "apple generic" means that the certificate that has the above mentioned fields, and is used for signing the app, must be either Apple's certificate or a code signing certificate issued by Apple.

All in all this means that you cannot just sign your program with any certificate and expect it to pass these GateKeeper rules. I.e. you cannot just create a certificate with one of those fields in it and sign it yourself.

You indicate that your ultimate goal is to submit the app to the Mac App Store. In that case, you need to use the "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" certificate for signing - and then submit the app to the Mac App Store.

What you're trying to do in practice is to actually run the app on a Mac before it has gone through the Mac App Store. If this is what you want to do, you need to sign the app with the "Developer ID Application" certificate instead.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. I actually just found this as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/RequirementLang/RequirementLang.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH5-SW1

Comment: So, field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9 means X509 certificate with extension OID=1.2.840... I'm testing locally with "Mac Developer: X Y" cert which only has an extension with OID 1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.12. However, this OID doesn't appear in the output of spctl --list, so no rule for it. I guess that explains why it doesn't work but shouldn't 6.1.12 be in spctl --list so that developer signed MAS apps work? I'm kind of new to app signing and it's all very confusing. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: BTW, I'd give you a thumb up, but it says I don't have enough reputation points!

Comment: The idea is that the certificate that has signed the app must be have this particular field, to indicate that it is for the Mac App Store, and the certificate must be Apple's or a code signing certificate issued by Apple. Basically, this means that you cannot just "make your own" certificate with that field and expect it to pass GateKeeper. As you want to submit the app to the Mac App Store, you must use the "3rd Party Mac Developer" certificate to sign it and submit it to the app store. If you want to run it locally without passing through the App Store, you need to use the [...]

Comment: "Developer ID Application" certificate.

Comment: Thanks. I was going by: https://www.electron.build/code-signing which has a mas-dev target that allows you to use "Apple Development: or Mac Developer" certificate + provisioning profile to locally test an app store build. I see they released testflight a few months age, so guessing they maybe booted OID 6.1.12 from the gatekeeper rules to force you to use testflight instead? The problem is that my uploaded builds say "Not Available for Testing" and I've no idea why, so I can't use testflight.

Comment: About to give up on App Store builds for now anyway, as it's been really frustrating and has consumed so much time trying every combination with nothing really working and not very good diagnostic tools. The user experience would be limited anyway due to the sandbox. Guess I lost $99 + a lot of time and hair. However, I think we answered the main question anyway and I now know more about spctl rules than I ever thought I would need to. Thank you so much for spending your time to help with this!!

Comment: No, they haven’t changed any rules after the introduction of TestFlight. You should have written that this is your first time trying to do this - I assumed you’re were an experienced user trying something out of the ordinary and looking for technical details. As a first time user, you should just use the Automatic setting and let it choose the right certificate automatically. This is normally quite un-eventful. For local testing remember that your Mac must be registered in the provisioning profile.

Comment: Your frustrations are actually with Electron and not TestFlight or Apple’s process as such - usually this all goes by very easy without the user having to do anything really - but for Electron it’s more complicated as you need to manually handle the provisioning profiles. My understanding is that for Electron when you have “Not available for testing” you can still submit it for review and test it with TestFlight afterwards. I think you’ll have more success asking in the Electron community, and/or trying to submit this as an issue with the Electron build/release process.